# Do I have to declare data in axios config

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I have two different end points.  One is

```
sentPost: function() {
  axios
    .post("/article", {
      title: this.title,
      content: this.editorContent
    }) // axios.<method>(url, {<data>})
    .then(({ data }) => {
      Swal.fire("Success!", "Article Posted!", "success");
      this.$emit("pagecontrol", "explore");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      let fields = err.response.data.join(" | ");
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: "Oops...",
        text: fields
      });
    });
}
```

and the other one is

```
destroy: function(article) {
  let id = article._id;
  axios
    .delete("/article", {
      data: {
        id
      }
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      Swal.fire("Success!", "Article Deleted!", "success");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      let fields = err.response.data.join(" | ");
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: "Oops...",
        text: fields
      });
    });
}
```

Why in the second one do I have to declare "data" in the axios config. I mean, in the first one I don't need to declare "data" but I still can access req.body from it.

I used to code axios config like this.

```
axios.get(url, {
  data
})
```

I never had an error with that before, but now I need to declare "data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not send a body in `DELETE`. You should use it like `GET`, and pass parameters in the URL.

### Read: [Axios API](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api), [DELETE body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299696/4559414)

#### Request method aliases:

```
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
axios.delete(url[, config])
```

#### Request Config:

```
{
...
  // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  },
...
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadIlham, If my answer has been helpful, accept it as a solution.